Using a generator in a for loop returns only the first element
I'm passing a generator as a variable to a method that iterates over it. But I'm getting only the first element of all possible permutations and getting a StopIteration exception. I'm using yield inside a for loop of my generator and I can't understand why this error is happening. Can you help me understand what I am doing wrong, please?
The code:
from itertools import permutations
from collections.abc import Generator

def unique_permutations(words, permutation_dict, **kwargs):
    try:
        permutation = generate_sorted_permutations(words)
        perm, comp = find_unique_permutation_composition(permutation=permutation, permutation_dict=permutation_dict, **kwargs)
    except StopIteration:
        permutation = generate_unsorted_permutations(words)
        perm, comp = find_unique_permutation_composition(permutation=permutation, permutation_dict=permutation_dict, **kwargs)
    permutation_dict[perm] = id
    return perm, comp


def find_unique_permutation_composition(permutation, permutation_dict, **kwargs):
    for p in permutation:
        composition = string_composition(perm_word=p, **kwargs)
        if composition not in permutation_dict:
            return p, composition
    raise StopIteration()


def generate_sorted_permutations(string: str, length: int = 5) -> Generator[str, None, None]:
    """
    Generate sorted permutations of given lenght (default: 5)
    """
    positions = list(range(len(string)))
    perms = (
        p
        for p in permutations(positions, length)
        if all(p[i] < p[i + 1] for i in range(length - 1)) # sorted permutations filter
    )
    for p in perms:
        try:
            permutation = "".join(string[i] for i in p)
            yield permutation
        except KeyError as e:
            print(f"Erro ao gerar permutação ordenada para {string} com p={p}: {e}")


def generate_unsorted_permutations(string: str, length: int = 5) -> Generator[str, None, None]:
    """
    Generates any permutation of any lenght (up to the given lenght)
    """
    positions = list(range(len(string)))
    length = len(string) if len(string) < length else length #allows permutations on strings of lower lenght
    perms = (
        p
        for p in permutations(positions, length)
    )
    for p in perms:
        try:
            permutation = "".join(string[i] for i in p)
            yield permutation
        except KeyError as e:
            print(f"Erro ao gerar permutação para {string} com p={p}: {e}")

When I define the method find_unique_permutation_composition like this it runs over all permutations as expected (when needed):
def find_unique_permutation_composition(permutation, permutation_dict, **kwargs):
    p = next(permutation)
    composition = string_composition(perm_word=p, **kwargs)
    while composition in permutation_dict:
        p = next(permutation)
        composition = string_composition(perm_word=p, **kwargs)
    if composition not in permutation_dict:
        return p, composition
    else:
        raise StopIteration()

It's my first time working with generators. What am I doing wrong? Aren't they supposed to work in for loops?

How do you call it? This just defines some functions, but doesn't call them. find_unique_permutation_composition in particular looks wrong, but I need the full reproduction before I can validate the fix.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration If a generator code directly or indirectly raises StopIteration, it is converted into a RuntimeError (retaining the StopIteration as the new exception’s cause).

Should you be adding composition to permutation_dict someplace in find_unique_permutation_composition() rather than after calling that method twice?

find_unique_permutation_composition looks like it's supposed to be a generator, but the way you're using it is odd. Anyway, please narrow the code down to the exact problem you're struggling with. It would be great if you could provide the [example].
